# How to prevent copying images each time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows Store App with many, many images (large and small icons in 4 scales). Simply building my app takes upwards of 5 minutes each time. I believe it is recopying each image each time I'm building the app, even if I've only changed a view or a code-behind. Is there a way to prevent it from doing this? I realize it's likely repackaging the App every single time (about a 20MB package). Hopefully there is a way to reduce this time though.

Comment: How are the images compiled in you appication, are they internal or external resources?

Comment: Internal. They're part of the project itself.

Comment: Is there a setting for "Copy if Newer"?

Comment: They are currently set to "Do not copy", with a Build Action of "Content". There is a "Copy if newer" option though.